# Pandas - scatter matrix set title

Tags: python, pandas, plot, title, scatter-plot

I'm searching for a way to set a title to Pandas `scatter matrix`:

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
scatter_matrix(data, alpha=0.5,diagonal='kde')
```

I tried `plt.title('scatter-matrix')` but it creates a new figure.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you need `suptitle`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix

scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.5,diagonal='kde') 
plt.suptitle('scatter-matrix')

plt.show()
```

Comment: scatter_matrix has no attribute title..it's different from a pure scatter plot